# Bad file descriptor when trying to send message from client to server

Tags: python

I need to be able to send a message as client to the server and get the message back from the server in my client's console.

However when I try to implement this I keep getting the error:

```
line 64, in <module>
s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

My client:

```
     import socket

HOST = 'localhost'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 12000        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)


print('Received', repr(data))






while True:
    message = input("write something:")
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print("Recieved from server: " + data)
```

My server:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 12000        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: It is now updated with the whole traceback.

Comment: In your client, using the `with` statement means once the code exits the block, the socket is closed. So either include all your code inside that block, or just write code to close the socket (`s.close()`) at the end of the client code yourself.

Comment: You can read about with statement here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement